# npm run start faild, meet the nodejs.AppWorkerDiedError

Tags: node.js

It's node.js problem, when I use npm run debug, meet AppWorkerDiedError. I used egg.js and added log below.

```
ERROR 10032 nodejs.AppWorkerDiedError: [master] app_worker#1:10058 died (code: 1, signal: null, suicide: false, state: dead), current workers: []
    at Master.onAppExit (/Users/zdm/web/wqapi/node_modules/egg-cluster/lib/master.js:510:21)
    at Master.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Messenger.sendToMaster (/Users/zdm/web/wqapi/node_modules/egg-cluster/lib/utils/messenger.js:137:17)
    at Messenger.send (/Users/zdm/web/wqapi/node_modules/egg-cluster/lib/utils/messenger.js:102:12)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/zdm/web/wqapi/node_modules/egg-cluster/lib/master.js:353:22)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (internal/cluster/master.js:188:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
name: "AppWorkerDiedError"
pid: 10032
hostname: ZDMdeMBP.lan

2020-06-17 18:39:41,743 ERROR 10032 [master] app_worker#1:10058 start fail, exiting with code:1
2020-06-17 18:39:41,743 ERROR 10032 [master] exit with code:1
2020-06-17 18:39:41,761 ERROR 10038 [agent_worker] receive disconnect event on child_process fork mode, exiting with code:110
2020-06-17 18:39:41,763 ERROR 10038 [agent_worker] exit with code:110
```

Comment: I have missing important log "[app_worker] server got error: bind EADDRINUSE null:17002, code: EADDRINUSE" The problem should be port 17002 in use. I have killed the application who used the port 17002. This problem has been resolved. The problem is not related to egg.js framework.  You can find answer here. https://github.com/eggjs/egg/issues/3565

Comment: so, due to bind EADDRINUSE null:17002. I just kill -9 17002. And then it works